# Assert Specify Text Present or not

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify whether specific Banner is present or not , I tried by storing src value of an image and comparing it , but i am not able to get it ,

Also related text will change but banner name uploaded will be same , so i need to assert my store value with that .

Here is my code

```
public void testSsssss() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/?country=US");
    String storze = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt=\"website banner\"]")).getAttribute("outerHTML");
    System.out.println(storze);
    assertEquals(storze, storze.contains("bannerbanner-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272-881.gif"));
  }
```

Value store in storze is :

```
 img
src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/bannername-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272-88.gif"
alt="bannerbanner" height="289" width="677"
```

I need to check with this text "`bannername-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272-88.gif`".

Not able to automate.Code will be much appreciated .

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please reframe it. Also paste complete html markup and what you need to assert against what. People will answer your question only when they have all inputs in hand.

Comment: You need to assert that storz variable should contain this string "bannerbanner-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272-881.gif" right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question what I come to know that you want to assert your storz value with banner name, so if it is the case then you should try this :

```
boolean flag = false;
    if (storz
            .contains("bannerbanner-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272-881.gif")) {
        flag = true;
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(flag, true);
```

And I noticed you are asserting Boolean value with String.

Comment: Thanks it work , but i am right now facing another problem , As banner which value i am storing is dynamic its name get changes  ; it can be 88.gif or 881 gif . How do i handle that case.

Comment: The expected will always be same? Is the full string getting change?

Comment: Not full string only last text that is 881.gif or sometime 88.gif

Comment: You want to assert only that this string should be "bannerbanner-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272" , I think last text is  not your concern. SO you can use only  if (storz
            .contains("bannerbanner-2015-summersplashout_AffBanners-664x272")) {

Comment: Yes I am following only as suggested , Thanks

Comment: @YouthIndia Please accept the answer which have solved your problem , if you are new to stack overflow you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use assertTrue instead of assertEquals in your code.